# Issue with swapped axes using projinfo/gdaltransform

Tags: gdal, proj

I'm attempting to perform a coordinate transform operation using gdaltransform (version 3.6.0). Because of the possibility of different transform candidates when the transform involves a change in datum, I prefer to use the -ct option and pass a proj string generated by projinfo rather than using the -s_src and -t_src options so that the transform being applied is explicitly defined.

When I use the projinfo command for my current transform:

```
projinfo -s EPSG:3116 -t EPSG:32617 --spatial-test intersects -o PROJ --single-line
```

It generates a proj string where the X and Y axes are, seemingly, flipped. Feeding the output proj string into gdaltransform gives me a wrong result:

```
echo '574318 871222 0' | gdaltransform -ct '+proj=pipeline +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1 +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=4.59620041666667 +lon_0=-74.0775079166667 +k=1 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=utm +zone
=17 +ellps=WGS84'
```

`1142609.86211403 82922.7967677774 0`

Compare this with the correct result achieved when using the -s_src and -t_src options of gdaltransform:

```
echo '574318 871222 0' | gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:3116 -t_srs EPSG:32617
```

`843906.183127754 379007.884866433 0`

If I manually modify the Proj string and change the +order parameter or swap my input X and Y coordinates I can also get the expected result.

My question really is whether anyone can explain the inconsistency between using gdaltransform with the -s_src and -t_src options and using projinfo as I have here then using gdaltransform with the -ct option?

Am I doing anything wrong or is there a bug somewhere in either projinfo and/or gdaltransform relating to this particular coordinate transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native coordinate axis order of the source system is Northing-Easting https://epsg.org/crs_3116/MAGNA-SIRGAS-Colombia-Bogota-zone.html?

> Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: northing, easting (N,E). Orientations: north,
> east. UoM: m.

Because of that the pipeline contains axisswap `+order=2,1` when it converts the coordinates into UTM that is using the Easting-Northing order. Use the Northing-Easting order in the input or remove the axisswap.

Gdaltransform is using the so called "traditional GIS order" that means that the first coordinate is always longitude or Easting, and the second coordinate is latitude or Northing.

Comment: Aha, there always seems to be something to trip you up. Just the answer I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: thank you for the link to epsg.org. I've had a hard time to understand using GdalTransform from EPSG:32632 (East, North) to EPSG:31467 (North, East).