# Order of coordinates when transforming with GDAL in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, epsg

I'm trying to use GDAL in Python to transform coordinates from one CRS to another.
More specifically, from **MGI / Austria GK M31** ([EPSG:31258](https://epsg.io/31258)) to **WGS 84** ([EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857)). For example, I want to transform the point (432000, 299500):

```
# trans.py

from osgeo import gdal, osr

gdal.UseExceptions()
crs_WGS84 = osr.SpatialReference()
crs_WGS84.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
crs_GKM31 = osr.SpatialReference()
crs_GKM31.ImportFromEPSG(31258)
x, y = (432000, 299500)
trans_to_latlon = osr.CoordinateTransformation(crs_GKM31, crs_WGS84)
lat, lon, _ = trans_to_latlon.TransformPoint(x, y)
print(f"({x}, {y}) -> ({lat:.4f}, {lon:.4f})")
```

This gives me

```
$ python trans.py
(432000, 299500) -> (49.0072, 11.2753)
```

But according to [this calculator](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=31258&t_srs=4326&ops=1618&x=432000.0000000&y=299500.0000000) the result should be `(47.8338, 13.0921)`.
So I tried swapping the order of the input point (`lat, lon, _ = trans_to_latlon.TransformPoint(y, x)`) and get the correct transformation:

```
$ python trans.py
(432000, 299500) -> (47.8338, 13.0921)
```

**However**: If I transform from the CRS **ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N** ([EPSG:25832](https://epsg.io/25832)), I don't have to swap the order of the input point:

```
# trans2.py

from osgeo import gdal, osr

gdal.UseExceptions()
crs_WGS84 = osr.SpatialReference()
crs_WGS84.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
crs_UTM32N = osr.SpatialReference()
crs_UTM32N.ImportFromEPSG(25832)
x, y = (294000, 5628000)
trans_to_latlon = osr.CoordinateTransformation(crs_UTM32N, crs_WGS84)
lat, lon, _ = trans_to_latlon.TransformPoint(x, y)
print(f"({x}, {y}) -> ({lat:.4f}, {lon:.4f})")
```

Which gives me the result I'm looking for (compared with [the calculator](https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=25832&t_srs=4326&ops=1149&x=294000.0000000&y=5628000.0000000)):

```
$ python3 trans2.py 
(294000, 5628000) -> (50.7671, 6.0786)
```

How do I know the correct order in which to pass the east-west (x) and north-south (y) coordinate to `CoordinateTransformation`?

Comment: There's a significant difference between WGS84 (4326) where X,Y vs lat,lon order matters, and Web Mercator (3857), which only has X,Y order.

Comment: @nieswand - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445205/issue-with-swapped-axes-using-projinfo-gdaltransform Look at the native order of the CRS.

Comment: The links that you provided show that information. https://epsg.io/31258 -> Coordinate system: Cartesian 2D CS. Axes: northing, easting (X,Y). Orientations: north, east. UoM: m.

Comment: @user30184 That's true. I guess my question is how I could get this information in a program that could encounter any kind of CRS and try to build a transformation to WGS84.

Comment: It is already answered for sure and not so long time ago. Would you mind searching the archives? If you don't find anything I may try then.

Comment: Here is something about using projinfo with Python https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461135/axes-labels-names-of-qgscoordinatereferencesystem/461146#461146.